# Ubuntu 12.10 firefox v19.0 fails to install missing plugins for adobe flash

Tags: 12.10, firefox, flash, plugins

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Windows 8 machine, using Firefox for web browsing.

But for flash based sites, I get this missing plug-in error "Additional plugins are needed to display all the medias on this page", but if i go to the Adobe flash page and download and copy the files from the ***.tar.gz, this problem is not going away. I got Ubuntu 64 bit and found this message from the size when downloaded the tar file.

Adobe Flash Player version 11.2.202.273
Your system: Linux 64-bit, Firefox | 6.90 MB

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?fpchrome

install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

and that would install flash plugin.